# Rails Paperclip doesn't understand the same convert options as ImageMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

Trying to set max width to 1280 when above 600Kb and not a .gif:

```
has_attached_file :main_image,
  :styles => {:original => "" },
  :convert_options => {
    :original => lambda { |instance| (instance.main_image_file_name.index(/\.gif/,-4).nil? && instance.main_image.size > 600000) ? "-resize 1280>" : "" }
  },
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_:basename.:extension",
  :url => "/system/:class/:attachment/:id_:basename.:extension"
```

Getting this in my logs:

```
Command :: convert '/var/folders/hn/2q5wpxh52nn_3nk9wwskr48w0000gn/T/5827912cb359afd550a72bf4f54b109020141119-76993-1i6nij6.png[0]' -auto-orient -resize 1280> '/var/folders/hn/2q5wpxh52nn_3nk9wwskr48w0000gn/T/5827912cb359afd550a72bf4f54b109020141119-76993-1i6nij620141119-76993-q0m833'
sh: 1280: Bad file descriptor
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Error: There was an error processing the thumbnail for 5827912cb359afd550a72bf4f54b109020141119-76993-1i6nij6>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here:

1. Paperclip w/ Rails will often require you to add `\\` in front of `<` or `>` characters, as in `1280x\\>`
2. Also, Paperclip always needs those x's, even when just doing width (`1280x\\>` and not `1280\\>`).

Here's my full solution for setting max width to 1280 when above 600Kb and not a .gif:

```
has_attached_file :main_image,
  :styles => {:original => "" },
  :convert_options => {
    :original => lambda { |instance| (instance.main_image_file_name.index(/\.gif/,-4).nil? && instance.main_image.size > 600000) ? "-resize 1280x\\>" : "" }
  },
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_:basename.:extension",
  :url => "/system/:class/:attachment/:id_:basename.:extension"
```